# osmdroid: can it rotate captions on map?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I built [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) from source,
and ran OpenStreeMapViewer as documentation suggested.

And when I rotate map with two finger I see that
caption rotated with whole map, so it is hard to read
them. If for example map is rotated to south, captions are
rotated upside to down.
Is any hack to not rotate captions with map?
Or it uses only open street map data in form of bitmaps,
and it is impossible with osmdroid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Captions (labels) are part of the *raster* images ([tiles)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). You can't rotate them without rotating the images. The only option is to render the map yourself using *vector* tiles.

Comment: So osmdroid can only work with prerender raster, and no code to support vector?

Comment: As far as I know it is possible to use mapsforge (a vector map library) with osmdroid. There are some examples on the Internet but I've never done it myself.

Comment: What sense then use osmdroid+mapsforge, if it is possible to use just maspforge?

Comment: I guess it depends on the required functionality if mapsforge is enough.